# Control excel export

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel

So basically got laravel project and got to export tables in excel. I'm using [this](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) for the export. Till now i only export from array or in my case.

```
public function exportGames()
{
  $export = Games::all();
  Excel::create('Games Data', function($excel) use($export){
     $excel->sheet('Games', function($sheet) use($export){
        $sheet->fromArray($export);
     });
  })->export('xlsx');
}
```

This however returns full table data, which include some field I to be gone (timestamps etc.). Also relational tables is not possible to display (only in the actual table on the page). Spend hours in the documentation still don't understand how to do it. Wanna rip my hair off. How do  modify columns to export. Thanks in advice.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to do? Do you want only few columns from a table? Or you want to format the data before it is exported?

Comment: Got table on the page, which  displays data from relational tables and when I want to export this  table it's not possible because can't select only the columns, (without timestamps for example) which don't get displayed on the page but still go them in the excel file. Since its $export = Games::all();

Comment: Show us the query you use to show the table you want to be exported please.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy There is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple enough:

```
$export = Games::select(['client_game_id', 'client_game_name', 'gameid', 'description', 'game_type', 'db_name', 'short_name'])->get();
```

You'll only see those columns in your exported XLS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
$export = Games::all();
  Excel::create('Games Data', function($excel) use($export){
     $excel->sheet('Games', function($sheet) use($export){
       foreach ($export as $key => $value) {
                $exports[] = array('email' => $value['email'], 'name' =>$value['name']);
            } 
     $sheet->fromArray($exports);
     });
  })->export('xlsx');
```